# SSIS Package Runtime

Tags: ssis

I need to create a table called PackageRun that tracks how long it takes to run my package.  Essentially it should store the StartTime & EndTime of the package and creates a calculated column in the table called duration.  I am a total newbie to 
SSIS so any help would be appreciated.  I have 2 variables called StartTime and EndTime.  StartTime has the expression @[System::StartTime] and EndTime has the expression GETDATE().

When I run the package, my table in SSMS only shows the column headings...not even pulling over date information, let alone any duration data.  Could someone please assist? I was told to create this as a data flow task with a derived column from my variables.

Thank you

Comment: SSIS has a integrated logging mechanism to track operations like start date, end date, fails, warnings, etc. Right click the background of the DTS and click on Logging. You can make it log directly to a SQL Server database (uses custom SSIS stored procedures to log the data). You can also overwrite this SP to log the info to any table you want, with the format or validations you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to give you an answer to your specific problem without seeing what you've done. Your description is vauge, perhaps you've missed to map your data in the dataflow.. With that said, I'll give you some general ideas how you can obtain what you are looking for. There are many ways to do this so I'll post three options that I use.

**Option 1.**
Use T-SQL or stored procedures (in an Execute SQL Task) in the beginning of the package to log the start time, package name, etc. and one to log the end time, calculated duration etc.

**Option 2.**
If you execute the package as a step in an agent job you can find this information in ssisdb catalog.executions table (this table does not log child package exections)

**Option 3.** (if you for example are loading hundreds of files and want to track the duration time for each file load). 
Do it in the dataflow